# Looking for a sci-fi / fantasy book about a boy named Flea

Tags: story-identification

In this story, it is in the far future so that it feels like a fantasy story. The protagonist is a boy named Flea with one shriveled leg. He gets dumped in a hole by his adopted family of orcs (or trolls?). He finds a cave and keeps journeying deeper into the earth. Along the way, he finds traps and puzzles that he solves, allowing him to continue. Among them, he finds a room with flying girl-like beings, which aren't afraid of him. He kills an animal there for food, and then gets in big trouble. At the end of the journey, he meets a wizard.

Any idea what this book is called, or who wrote it?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I'm looking for it too:
http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55178/fantasy-piece-involving-different-worlds-and-a-crippled-protagonist

Comment: The main part I remembered was the bit where he fell forever, with somewhat realistic treatment of terminal velocity.

Comment: Yeah it sounds like the same book. Well, good luck (to us!)

Comment: I remember one other part. He finds a room with flying girl-like beings, which aren't afraid of him. He kills an animal there for food, and then gets in big trouble.

Comment: Was it YA and was it a novel or series?

Comment: Not YA; it had mature stuff for mature readers. It was a single, stand-alone novel. The version I had was hardback, with some interesting black-and-white illustrations scattered through the book. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found it! Nevermind. Thanks for trying to help me out guys, regardless!

The book is called "The World and Thorinn" by Damon Knight. His name is Thorinn, but his nickname is Flea.